# iptables to block http and ssh in one direction

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have a topology where there is a Linux as a router that connects two Linux, and I want to use iptables to filter ssh and HTTP in one direction.
I used the below code but it didn't work!
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFzL.png)

Comment: Some context is missing in your question. How are packets forwarded from 192.168.18.128 to 192.168.17.128? If 192.168.18.129 is truly a router, then 192.168.18.128 would not know about 192.168.17.128, and you would filter incoming HTTP and SSH connection requests in the INPUT chain.

Comment: 192.168.18.129 is also a Linux, and in 192.168.18.128 I used 192.168.18.129 as default gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script should work for http, but it is not really nice. I woulde use something like this:

```
IPTABLE=/sbin/iptables

$IPTABLE -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLE -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLE -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

$IPTABLE -F
$IPTABLE -X

$IPTABLE -F -t nat
$IPTABLE -X -t nat

$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#http
$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
#https
$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# ssh
$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# icmp
$IPTABLE -A FORWARD  -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Once rules are woking I recommend to  do a `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`. With the `iptables-persistent` packet the rules are loaded at boot.
In addition to the iptables Rules you need

1. IP Forwarding enabled on your Gateway.
2. a route for the external network on your internal host
3. a route for the internal network on your external host

Comment: Instead of generic `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` I would recommend these two rules: `$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `$IPTABLE -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -j ACCEPT`. Then you wouldn't need the 3 port specific FORWARD rules.

Comment: @Doug, first: your recommendation does not meet the request limiting allowed connections to http ans ssh. I already extented it with https and icmp. Seconed: packets of exsisting sessions are alwaxy handeled by rule one (conntrack) in your recommendation all packets from ens33 to ens38 must run through the whole ruleset - not recommended.